# CSS has formatted itself in a confusing way

Tags: css, html

Some CSS on my screen seems to be automatically giving itself a margin from the top but not showing it correctly.

Example:

[image]

The green box is inside the image.

I have a feeling this is breaking the format I want which is to have the logo too the left and the contact and search bar too the right:

[image]

Here is my CSS:

```
.span6 img {
float: left;
}

img.logo {
    float: left;
    max-width: 350px;
    height: auto;

}

#contact 
{
    float: left;
    font-size: 2em; 
    color: black;
}
```

and my HTML:

```
<div class="row top-header">
    <div class="span12" data-motopress-type="dynamic-sidebar" data-motopress-sidebar-id="header-sidebar">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar("header-sidebar"); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div style="" class="span6" data-motopress-type="static" data-motopress-static-file="static/static-logo.php">
        <img src="http://bradlyspicer.net/autokentcare/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/logo2.png" class="logo">
<div id="contact"><span style="margin-left:50px; float: left;">01843 123456<br><div style="margin-top:15px; display:inline-block;"><form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>/">
<div><input type="text" size="12px" name="s" id="s" value="Write your search and hit Enter" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"/>
<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" class="btn""/></span></div>
</div>
</form></span>
    </div>
```

URL: http://www.bradlyspicer.net/autokentcare/

After doing suggested changes this happens when I shrink the window:

[image]

Comment: is this bootstrap 2.x?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean tbh. You don't mean `body { margin: 0; }` do you? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/9M5ec/2/)

Comment: have you checked the margins for `body` tag?

Comment: @ Hunter, it's Wordpress  @Ruddy Your demo is exactly how my site is at the moment and it's still not working. Edited OP to have my URL

Comment: @BradlySpicer My demo is your code but added the `margin:0` on the `body`. Also its not got the search under the logo its to the side.

Comment: @Ruddy after adding margin: 0; it still hasn't changed and the search bar isn't on the side of my logo in my site :(

Comment: @BradlySpicer `Your requested host "www.bradlyspicer.co.uk" could not be resolved by DNS.` So cant help you xD

Comment: www.bradlyspicer.net is the proper domain

Comment: @BradlySpicer Your site looks fine to me. What browser are you using?

Comment: @Ruddy http://www.bradlyspicer.net is the wrong site. That is different, I am designing http://bradlyspicer.net/autokentcare/ and I am using Chrome

Comment: @BradlySpicer Yup same, here I see no problem with it

Comment: @Ruddy kind of all fixed, The navigation issue is now fixed. Didn't know about clearing floats. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your logo and search bar inside of a div that has a width set on it to 560 (span6 class)  If you remove that class it should work a bit better for you.

Comment: Hey Box, thanks for pointing that out, completely slipped my mind. I've done that, I've now set the #contact to float right and it's worked, yay! However, it's now removed the responsive element from the nav? When I shrink the window the nav bar repeats.

Thanks

Comment: instead of removing the class, make it a span12 and it should work

Comment: also, dont forget to clear your floated elements, otherwise the next row will overlap into the header